# I have problems creating folders in windows with Ñ on name

Tags: c++

My code works well always, but when I want to name a folder for example "Año" it fails.
I would like to find a solution because I don't want this bug in my program.

The folder name is passed as parameter by console, so here is my code for creating the folder:

```
//nameFolder is taken before, here I link the complete path
wstring pat(L"C:\\Users\\Paul\\Documents\\");
pat.append(nameFolder);
wcout << pat;
const wchar_t* param = pat.c_str();
wcout << "\n" <<&param;

_tmkdir(param);
```

Comment: You need to use unicode, not ascii. std::stringstream is for ascii, same for std::string.
Use ONLY unicode and you'll be fine.

Comment: "Works Always" with a case where it does not work is not Always. Also, be very explicit as to what fails. Does the `_tmkdir` fail?

Comment: _tmkdir creates the folder with an incorrect name. So it works, but not as expected, because special character Ñ doesn't appear. I'll try to change the code and use unicode

Comment: I still have problems, even using unicode. I declare "wstring folderName;" Then I read it from console with "std::getline(std::wcin, folderName);" After read it, I show it on console with wcout and the name is ok. Finally, I create the folder with the same code as I put in the question, but using wstringstream and wstring instead of stringstream and string. The name I see in the folder is A¤o instead of Año.

Comment: Well, I just update the code up. Do you have any idea?

Comment: When I see the console I can read C:\Users\TJS05\Desktop\ENSAYOS\Año, but if I copy it and paste here it shows C:\Users\TJS05\Desktop\ENSAYOS\A¤o . Of course folder's name is also A¤o.  My main is declared as _tmain, and I also used wmain before. In addition my project properties has "use unicode character set"

Comment: Solved, the problem was console encoding

Answer (score 3):

Use wide-character strings for everything. `std::wstringstream` instead of `std::stringstream` and  `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`.

To see what's going on with your code, try printing out `d` after `std::string d = st.str();`.